# How to control charging led on windows laptop or winPad

Tags: windows, led

I want to get charging led color in my code, but after a lot of searching I found that there is no standard interface on windows.
Is there any interface which I can access to get charging led status?

Comment: It's unlikely that you can *control* the LED, but it seems possible to get the current charging status. (When I Google `Windows get charging status` there seem to be results.)

Comment: The interface will be completely proprietary and custom based on who built the laptop.  Regardless, you'll require a kernel-mode driver to interface with the hardware.  There probably already exists one provided by the manufacturer that you can talk to via `DeviceIoControl()`, but it's unlikely to be documented.

Comment: Thanks for your kindly help, what I want to do is to get the LED status(showing different color depending on charging status). If there is no standard interface, I have to ask drivers' team to provide.

Comment: Not every laptop has a charging indicator led. Therefor no standard interface exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will ask drivers' team to provide interfaces for me to get the LED status, while there is no standard interface on windows.